# Print the contents of String* from OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv, wrapper

I have a C wrapper (below) for opencv c++ imread I need to debug. The reason is when I wrap the C wrapper it in another language it doesn't work the filename parameter isn't being received right

```
 Mat* cv_imread(String* filename, int flags)
 {
    return new Mat(cv::imread(*filename, flags));
 }
```

So I'd need to debug it by doing something akin to the below function:

```
 using namespace std;

 Mat* cv_imread(String* filename, int flags) 
 {
    cout << filename; // but I'd need to find out how to print contents of filename other
                      //than just the pointer
    return new Mat(cv::imread(*filename, flags));
 }
```

so let's say `String* filename = "home/user/test.jpeg"`

that's what I'd need to print not the 8 or 9 character pointer location in memory.

So if someone could tell me how to dereference `String* filename` so I can `cout << filename-><add text here>;`

Comment: What the heck is `String`?

Comment: @crashmstr: It's a C wrapper for the OpenCV library. That's why it is tagged opencv.

Comment: @crashmstr, opencv comes with's own cv::String class lately ..

Comment: Consistent use of `cv::` prefix would be nice... and now sounds like a simple documentation search.

Comment: @adripanico Thanks for your comment...you actually answered my ? the best...you should post as answer so I can vote you up:)

Comment: But don't vote it up, mark it as correct! :D

Answer (score 1):

Use [c_str](http://www.ropencv.aduda.eu/doc/OpenCV/Cv/String.html#c_str-instance_method) to get the underlying pointer of a string:

`cout << filename->c_str() << endl;`

Consequently, this is the proper way to call `cv_imread` as well:

`return new Mat(cv::imread(filename->c_str(), flags));`

Answer (score 1):

Since `filename` is a pointer to a memory position (the first of the characters of your string), if you print out it this way:

```
cout << filename;
```

you will get the memory address.

If you want to get the data pointed by the pointer, just use:

```
cout << *filename;
```